# Python: Get unique numbers from a text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-re

Supposedly I have the following text:

```
text = "30 people work for 3 managers"
```

T
I want to extract only 3 from the above text. The above text is just an example and can be arbitrary. The following code seems right but doesn't work

```
find = re.findall(r"3", text)
```

The output of this code is

```
 ['3', '3']
```

```
find = re.findall(r"(\d+)", text)
```

The above would also not work because i would get 30 and 3 both. I specifically want to 3.

The output also is in list. How do I convert to string. I do not want to use .join method or for loop. I would be eventually applying this code to a df. so I can use the .apply() method

Comment: `re.findall('(3)[\s\.]', text)`  Look for three followed by space or period for end of sentence.

Comment: Maybe just `\b3\b`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you are trying to all occurrences of the number 3. The reason you are pulling

`['3','3']`

is because there are actually two '3's in your text. One for 30 as well.

You can use just find `" 3 "` instead of simply `"3"` to make sure to excuse other numbers like 30,33, 13, etc....

Comment: It will fail with "30 people work for 3".

Comment: You are right, didn't think about when 3 would be the end of the sentence.